# attr_accessor usage for a custom attribute of ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I need to implement a form with a **custom field** (which doesn't have it's reference in db) using a checkbox (boolean field).

if the checkbox is checked, the backend must write a certain many-to-many row and point it to the updated object.

The problem is my setter method in **article.rb** is not being accessed on form post.

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :highlight

  def highlight
  end

  def highlight=(arg)
    puts "NO ACCESS"
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @article] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, :label => "Title" %>
  <%= f.input :text, :as => :ckeditor %>
  <%= f.input :highlight, :as => :boolean, :label => "Highlight" %>
```

**article.rb(active_admin)**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  form partial: 'form'
  permit_params do
    permitted = [:title, :text, :highlight]
    permitted
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javkhlan, `attr_accessor :highlight` is short form for

```
def highlight
  @hightlight
end

def highlight=(highlight)
  @highlight = highlight
end
```

So, your code

```
def highlight
end

def highlight=(arg)
  puts "NO ACCESS"
end
```

Just rewrite methods generated by your `attr_accessor`. Try to remove these two methods and you'll be happy

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> attr_accessor :highlight

and check